# Vertex Labels Not appearing in iGraph Plot

Tags: r, igraph

I'm plotting a bipartite network in iGraph. The csv I used to create the graph is an edgelist formatted as follows

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| node1 | node3 |
| node4 | node7 |
| node1. | node4. |

From there I used to following code:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=FALSE)

bipartite_mapping(g)
V(g)$type <- bipartite_mapping(g)$type

plot(g)

plot(g, vertex.label.cex = 0.8, vertex.label.color = "black")

V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$type, "lightblue", "salmon")
V(g)$shape <- ifelse(V(g)$type, "circle", "square")
E(g)$color <- "lightgray"

plot(g, vertex.label.cex = 0.8, vertex.label.color = "black")
```

However, no matter what I do to alter the color labels or other vertex attributes, I cannot get the vertex lables (node1, node2, etc) to show up in the plot.

What am I missing?

Very grateful for the help! Driving myself crazy, I'm sure it's simple but I can't find an answer online.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
g <- make_graph(c("node1", "node3", "node4", "node7", "node1", "node4"), directed = FALSE)
g
V(g)$type <- bipartite_mapping(g)$type
V(g)$type

plot(g, layout=layout_as_bipartite, vertex.label.cex = 0.8, vertex.label.color = "red")

V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$type, "lightblue", "salmon")
V(g)$shape <- ifelse(V(g)$type, "circle", "square")
E(g)$color <- "lightgray"

plot(g, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

The outcome is:

```
IGRAPH fea8680 UN-- 4 3 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from fea8680 (vertex names):
[1] node1--node3 node4--node7 node1--node4

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

For me it works flawlessly.